# de Rham Cohomology with boundary conditions?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, de-rham-cohomology

de Rham cohomology can be used to establish the existence of some PDEs. For example, for every smooth function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R,$ whether there exist a vector field $\mathbf X$ such that $\nabla \cdot 
 \mathbf X = f$ depends on $H^3_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb R^3).$

However, we are often interested in problems with boundary data.

Can de Rham cohomology help with boundary data? To give a simple example, how to show that a solution to
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf X =f \text{ in } \Omega,\\
\mathbf X \cdot \mathbf n = 0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega. 
\end{cases}
$$
Exists? (Of course this is closely related to the Newmann problem, but can de Rham Cohomology help?)

Also the uniqueness - in general, without the boundary condition, the solution is certainly not unique. We may write the general solution in the form $\mathbf X + \nabla \times \mathbf A$ for an arbitrary vector potential $\mathbf A,$ again when $H^2_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb R^3) = 0.$ But this does not take into account the boundary data. How can we include the boundary condition in de Rham cohomology?

Edit: I am thinking about something similar to turning the sobolev space (NOT cohomology) $H^1(U)$ into the sobolev space $H^1_0(U).$

Comment: Check out [Hodge Decomposition - A Method for Solving Boundary Value Problems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540600169) by Günter Schwarz.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you. Let me take a look. Could you tell me what's the name of the construction I am looking for?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I don't have the book with me.